# 2D Baker map for image pixel shuffling matlab code

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, encryption

[image]I am trying to implement the discretized baker map for the shuffling of pixels,i am not able to understand the discretized version of it clearly.and neither am i able to implement it properly on matlab it always show index out of bounds error.
here is the link
http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-95972-4_16
please can somebody help. I am a beginner and this is my effort at it i know it is pathetic but still.

```
clc; 
Image=imread('C:\Users\AAA\Documents\lena_gray.gif');
[y,ymap]=imread('C:\Users\AAA\Documents\lena_gray.gif');
im=ind2gray(y,ymap);
%im=imresize(im,0.25);
I=im;
%ite=input('enter the number of iterations >');
[row,col]=size(im);

par=2;
for i=row:-1:1
for j=1:col
     if((1<=j)&&(j<257))
         rnew=floor(0.5*(i-mod(i-1,2)))+1;
         c_new=2*(j-1)+mod(i-1,2)+1;
      else
          rnew=floor(0.5*(i-mod(i-1,2)))+257;
          c_new=2*(j-257)+mod(i-1,2)+1;
     end
     encim(i,j)=im(rnew,c_new);
end
end 
encim=uint8(encim)
figure,imshow(encim)
impixelinfo
figure,imhist(encim)
if(imhist(encim)==imhist(I));
g=1
else
g=0
end
```

Comment: `1<=j<row/2` this is not valid in almost any language. `(1<=j) && (j<row/2)` maybe? Even if valid, its not doing what you think its doing. `1<=j` results in `1` or `0`. This number is always `<row/2`

Comment: thanx for the comments.but i have fixed this error.But after encryption the image shoulb be cut in half horizontally but my image i halved vertically.can you tell where i might be wrong

Comment: I can not see it fixed though. Show us the right code, not the wrong one

Comment: i have edited with the code.can you check

Comment: So whats the problem now?

Comment: actually after encryption the image should be halved horizontally and stacked on top of the other but my code does the half vertically and no stacking

Comment: can u check ander biguri